# Official "How to" for MVC Editor/Display Templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I have been using MVC Editor & Display Templates for a while, but have come to realize that there seems to be very little official documentation on MVC Editor/Display Templates (Html.EditorFor() and Html.DisplayFor()).  I found the basic [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834942%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) just showing the technical details (which on their own, are not very helpful), but I'm looking more for an official how-to, sort of like [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx).

Are Editor/Display Templates more of an afterthought, and not really widely enough used to justify more in-depth official documentation?

Or, am I blind, and what I'm looking for exists, I just haven't found it yet?

Comment: They are actually very well used by the default scaffolded view templates.

Comment: It's now 2017 and I have yet to find any docs or article(s) on how to edit a phone number within a template. e.g. `"(###) ###-####"` I'm still trying to figure out whether or not it's even possible!  :(

Comment: 2021; still almost impossible to find good explanations on custom real life complex partials. I however; keep finding 12-15 years old explanations using old mvc framework version 2.

Comment: Or it reverts to CORE examples not using RAZOR

Answer (score 3):

Official documentation? Don't know any off hand, but I know there are a ton of examples. In particular, I like *Phil Haack's discussion on model binding* to lists. It includes an example for an editor template in a pretty complicated example. There's source code there, too.

Since he's co-authored every MVC Wrox book, I consider him a pretty definitive source:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Here's another blog post (non-official) in a similar vein:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/03/30/collections-and-asp-net-mvc-templated-helpers-displayfor-editorfor.aspx

Answer (score 3):

best article that I have found for it is:

http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html

It explains how to create `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` templates really well.

Comment: Your definition of "really well" is a lot different than mine. That article has some simple tips but doesn't really explain anything in detail.

Comment: back in 2014 that 2012 article was good enough for us to move on  I guess times change 

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC have a lot of materials on http://www.asp.net/mvc with different examples. `EditorTemplates` and `DisplayTemplates` is spetial folders for models (like here [Quick Tips About ASP.NET MVC – Editor Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx)) and you asking about `html helpers`, not templates.

Comment: Except when you click go deeper it reverts to CORE

Comment: also; second link is 404