# Asp.net mvc 5 cross browser date picker and time picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser, datepicker, timepicker

I programming in mvc5 and i have problem.

My model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]        
public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes:                   new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new {    htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date,  "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Time, htmlAttributes:  new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time, new {  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use Google chrome date picker and time picker displays correctly, but when I use mozilla firefox this is only a textbox.
How i can to generalize it? I want always to have date picker and time picker.

[image: DataPicker and TimePicker in mozilla firefox and chrome]

Comment: The HTML5 `input type="date"` is not supported in FireFox. Refer [comparison table](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/firefox-40/ie-11/chrome-44/safari-9.0.html)

Answer (score 0):

The default editor template uses the html input type 'date', which is probably [not supported in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10). We created a custom [editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644640/official-how-to-for-mvc-editor-display-templates) which falls back to jquery date picker (choose whatever js date picker, there are lots) if the browser does not support the date input type.

You can test this feature using  [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/) if you want.