# How to display IEnumerable in view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable

Im doing comment section for product and have some troubles with displaying comments view. I made model from 2 models to display them in one view, but my way to display IEnumerable as list gets me an error. How can i modify my code to get this working?

Model

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult ProductDetails(int? id)
    {
        DetailsViewModel detailsViewModel = new DetailsViewModel();
        detailsViewModel.Product = db.Product.Find(id);//this is working
        detailsViewModel.Comments = db.Comments.Where(c => c.Id_Product == id).OrderBy(x => x.DateComment).ToList();
        return View(detailsViewModel);
    }
```

View

```
@model Database.Models.DetailsViewModel
<ul>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comments.DateComment) //getting error here 'IEnumerable<Comments>'
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comments.Comment)     // does not containt definiton for 'Comment'
<ul>
```

i want to get something like this:

2019-06-25: Foo

2019-06-25: FooFoo

Comment: You would need an `foreach`.

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DetailsViewModel' because 'DetailsViewModel' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to achieve your functionality. A foreach loop will iterate over your `IEnumerable` and display each element in the list. Specifically to your case, you can do:

```
<ul>
  @foreach(var comment in Model.Comments)
  {
   <li>@comment.DateComment</li>
   <li>@comment.Comment</li>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: use `@` before comment `<li>comment.DateComment</li>`

Comment: Sorry missed out on that. Have made the required edit. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `Model.DetailsViewModel.Comments` be `Model.Comments`?

Comment: yes, it should be `Model.Comments` ty for help, it solve the problem for me

Comment: <ul> needs to be closed

Answer (score 1):

Create a [DisplayTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644640/official-how-to-for-mvc-editor-display-templates) for your Comment model and then simply use

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comments)
```

which will loop through them and use the DisplayTemplate to render each.

Comment: it gives me back something weird `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_1F161BFA07EF87380337F5397E9B83A40B176F245617AD31ACF72F5F0598D1BF` instead of comments

Comment: Did you *Create a DisplayTemplate for your Comment model*, as the first words of the answer indicates you have to do?